# How To Remove Results from multiple selection statements that are equal to 0

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have this query and I want to remove results that are = 0.

```
declare @Teacher as nvarchar(50) ='Professor David'

select  'Science Class' as 'Study Type',
(select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SClass where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
union
select  'Science Lab' as 'Study Type',
(select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SLab where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
union
select  'Science Field' as 'Study Type',
(select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_field where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
```

I want to store this as a store procedure but I want to eliminate the outcoming results of the union that dont have the teacher declared 'Professor David'.

The results showing are:

```
Study Type        Number Of passing Students
Science Class     8
Science Lab       0
Science Field     1
```

The Results Required are:

```
Study Type        Number Of passing Students
Science Class     8
Science Field     1
```

As you can see I want to eliminate Science Lab  because the number of passing students are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take your existing query and make it a subquery.  Then, you can use a `where` clause to do the filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select  'Science Class' as [Study Type],
              (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SClass where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as [Number of Passing Students]
      union all
      select  'Science Lab' as 'Study Type',
              (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SLab where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as [Number of Passing Students]
      union all
      select  'Science Field' as 'Study Type',
              (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_field where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as [Number of Passing Students]
     ) t
where [Number of Passing Students] > 0;
```

I also changed the `union` to `union all`.  `union all` is more efficient because it does *not* remove duplicates, so it is a good idea to use that by default (unless you want to remove duplicates).  Also, I changed the column aliases to use square brackets rather than single quotes.  Use single quotes only for string constants and not for names of columns within a query.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response its 100% accurate!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this line at the end of each query

`group by teacher having count(Distinct StudentID) > 0`

This will return only records which has count more than 1

```
select  'Science Class' as [Study Type],
          (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SClass where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher group by teacher having count(Distinct StudentID) > 0) as [Number of Passing Students]
union all
select  'Science Lab' as 'Study Type',
          (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SLab where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher group by teacher having count(Distinct StudentID) > 0) as [Number of Passing Students]
union all
select  'Science Field' as 'Study Type',
          (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_field where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher group by teacher having count(Distinct StudentID) > 0) as [Number of Passing Students]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a derived table and filter out the rows which returns more than 0 rows.

```
 declare @Teacher as nvarchar(50) ='Professor David'

    select * from 
(    
        select  'Science Class' as 'Study Type',
        (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SClass where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
        union
        select  'Science Lab' as 'Study Type',
        (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_SLab where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
        union
        select  'Science Field' as 'Study Type',
        (select Count(Distinct StudentID) from Table_class_field where Grade = 'Passed' and Teacher= @Teacher) as 'Number of Passing Students'
) 
as DT
Where DT.cnt > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING clause allows you to filter results based on aggregation values.

The solution would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @Teacher AS nvarchar(50) ='Professor David'

SELECT  'Science Class' as 'Study Type',
    COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) as 'Number of Passing Students'
FROM    Table_class_SClass 
WHERE   Grade = 'Passed' 
AND Teacher= @Teacher
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) > 0
UNION
SELECT  'Science Lab' as 'Study Type',
    COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) as 'Number of Passing Students'
FROM    Table_class_SLab
WHERE   Grade = 'Passed' 
AND Teacher= @Teacher 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) > 0
UNION
SELECT  'Science Field' as 'Study Type',
    COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) as 'Number of Passing Students'
FROM    Table_class_Politics
WHERE   Grade = 'Passed' 
AND Teacher= @Teacher
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) > 0
```

As a small adendum though it looks like your database isn't normalised and you're making your queries more difficult for yourself by leaving it this way.
You may want to research database normalisation and apply some of the concepts to your own database.